# How can I access the anonymous function when I using vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I'm a quite new to Vue.js. I have a question.

I can't access something() function below.
How can I access something() function???
Thanks in advance :)

```
var vm= new Vue({
    data : {},
    created : {
        something();    //it doesnt work
    }

});

var something = function(){
    console.log("test")
}
```

Comment: This is working: https://fiddle.jshell.net/g3hpr18o/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not about Vue.
Hoisting is JavaScript's default behavior of moving declarations to the top of the current scope.
Hoisting applies to variable declarations and to function declarations.
Because of this, JavaScript functions can be called before they are declared:

```
something(5);

function something(y) {
 console.log("test")
}
```

Functions defined using an expression are not hoisted.
So, your can move `var something = function(){}` in the top, or use function declarations.